# How to execute the Rapportive gem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rapportive

I just started learning ruby on rails. I wanted to launch the rapportive gem (you can find here : https://rubygems.org/gems/rapportive/versions/0.0.1

But i don't know what should I do.. 
I found that in the documentation :

```
client = Rapportive::Search.new
client.search("alfredo@cool-tabs.com")
```

Can you help me please ?

More infos :

What I want to do : 
- I want to add a list of emails and print the result of Rapportive query in a specific page

What I already did so far : 
- I already created a first app with ruby on rails, it's just a library app (the one openclassroom teach you to create)
- I already installed the gem in the app

I just want to learn, sorry to bother you with newbie questions ahah

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about [rapportive gem](https://github.com/kjakub/rapportive). It is obsolete and not functional since Rapportive API change.